# C# with crystal reports columns from different tables

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, mysql-workbench

I think this was simple for some C# masters here..

Language: VS 2010 C# Windows Application
Database: MySQL Workbench CE
Reporting: Crystal Reports

I can generate a report from a single table but when I add a columns from the other table, the data of my report was becoming blank.. only the column name was left in the report... [This Was My Screenshots Of My Work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyV3l.png) and  [My Source Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilFhS.png)....

Advance Thank You To Those Who Wants To Help Me...

Answer (score 0):

I think your "productioninformation" table is empty from the Crystal Reports point of view.

Your query makes a inner join and returns a projection combining the two tables. So your dataadapter has only one table.

Hence, you need to break your query in two, so that the dataadapter will really have two tables or you need to change the Crystal Reports data schema to complies to your unique table in the dataadapter (if you are using a XSD schema, change it).

Answer (score 0):

You are using **inner join** between two tables (**productioninformation and warehouseinventory**), so all the data that is same on both table (depending on ProductCode condition) is binding, but i think one of your table does not fill the condition so that your data is showing.

you should use **Left inner join** in your query where you using inner join.

Maybe it will solve your problem.